# When creating a table from a folder of csv files header information is not read. How can I specify which file in the folder to use for headers?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

This issue can be reproduced on a community instance of [Databricks](https://databricks.com/signup#signup/community).

Using the airlines dataset, there is a folder with many files.  The first file has a header but the rest don't.

This statement will create a table with headers:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airline;
CREATE TABLE airline
USING CSV
OPTIONS (path "dbfs:/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00000", header "true")
```

This statement will create a table without headers:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airline;
CREATE TABLE airline
USING CSV
OPTIONS (path "dbfs:/databricks-datasets/airlines/part-00001", header "true")
```

This statement will create a table without headers:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS airline;
CREATE TABLE airline
USING CSV
OPTIONS (path "dbfs:/databricks-datasets/airlines/", header "true")
```

Is there a way to control where header information is read from?  Is there any documentation of all the options possible for the parameter `OPTIONS`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to read the header from one file and not the others. You have to read the data without headers and then filter out the header row using an appropriate `WHERE` clause.

There is no good documentation for all the delimited file reading options now that support is bundled into Spark 2.x. For reference, I still go back to the 1.x docs: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features